# Hibernate Validator - Using custom annotations instead of default?

Tags: hibernate, validation, annotations, default

I am participating in a project, which uses Hibernate as ORM. But the validation of the data is done with annotations at application level. So my question is - is it possible and okay I to use the already used annotations for validating, instead of adding usage of the default Hibernate Validator annotations to the already existing ones?

Answer (score 0):

No reason you can't just rely on application-level validations but...the annotations are actually of different types, and therefore both might be necessary or advised.

I view Hibernate validation annotations as persistence-layer only, ensuring that, at the very least, whatever goes into the database meets some bare minimum requirements.  They often do (and likely should) match what the database definition itself has (at least when you're dealing with RDBMs) but allow JPA/Hibernate to do some validation before taking the network/server hit of sending requests to the database server.

Application validation annotations are (should be?) specific to the business rules, usually more complex than what the database itself might require or know about.

One issue might be consistency between applications using the same persistence layer.  If you only rely on the application annotations and they're not validating the same - especially with regard to things like nullability, emptiness, legal values, etc. - then the data created/updated by one application might cause errors in the other.  If the very basic rules are only in the persistence layer, then you (hopefully) know the basics are correct.

Of course, the persistence validation annotations can do a lot for implementing/confirming business logic, so it really comes down to what you want to validate where.